# DOM manipulation not works in Component?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js

My AngularJS code is in JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvpsb8k3/), not runnable, but tells what it is:

The result looks like:

[image]
[image]

So, while I manipulate DOMs in `ngAfterViewInit`, the DOM elements are created but not show up? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oq72umb0/).

**CHANGES**

Before:

```
<svg #myChart>
</svg>
```

After:

```
<div #myChart>
</div>
```

Only change the `svg` tag to `div` tag.